# Golang pointer in Array

Tags: arrays, pointers, go

I want to know why this code can not change the value in the array

I try to modify the element in the array by pointer. Not by index.

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    array := []Type{}

    array = append(array, Type{2})
    array = append(array, Type{3})
    array = append(array, Type{4})
    array = append(array, Type{5})

    res := []*Type{}

    for _, a := range array {
        a1 := a
        res = append(res, &a1)
    }
    for _,v := range res {
        v1 := v
        v1.number++
    }
    for _, t := range res {
        fmt.Print(t.number)
    }
}
type Type struct {
    number int32
}
```

My expect result should be 3,4,5,6. But the result did not change, so I want to know the detail reason. I am new to Go. Please tell me detail

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please take some time when posting a question. Make it look good, make it as clear as possible, and also give your best to format it well. Thanks.

Comment: Your expectation is exactly what happens: https://play.golang.org/p/UMl2PltLKtq

Comment: Adding the line `fmt.Printf("%p %p\n",&a, &a1)` after `a1 := a` may help explain what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is **why the values in the original array did not get modified** then the answer is it is **because iteration item introduced in `range` is a copy of original item**. To fix your issue you could do something like:

```golang
for i := range array {
  res = append(res, &array[i])
}
```

Check out this references:

1. https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_clause
2. https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Range#gotchas
3. https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/16
4. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22791#issuecomment-345391395
5. https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/06/for-range-semantics.html